# Why isn't my table cell number bolded?

Tags: longtable, bold

I'm using Pandoc to convert Markdown to LaTeX. A subset of the output looks like this:

```
\documentclass[bachelor]{stpthesis}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lcll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
& f1 & precision & recall
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
None & 0.421022 & 0.507951 & 0.503386
\\\addlinespace
PPMI & 0.603329 & 0.637012 & 0.617783
\\\addlinespace
PLOG & 0.490976 & 0.622938 & 0.558508
\\\addlinespace
EPMI & \textbf{0.674587} & 0.675957 & 0.674943
\\\addlinespace
PLMI & 0.43577 & 0.512759 & 0.506313
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following result:
[image: PDF output]

As you can see in the LaTeX markup, the EPMI f1 score is supposed to be bolded, yet it doesn't turn up that way in the PDF output. Any idea why that is? The log file gives no indication of warnings considering the table formatting.

Thanks!

EDIT: I have realized that the problem seems to lie in the custom document class we are using. If you feel like looking further into it, you may take a look at the document class [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/utr3feqngec5q5k/stpthesis.zip).

Comment: Works fine here, can you create a complete example showing the problem?

Comment: Did you remember to compile the program twice?

Comment: @Mico Shouldn't make a difference for `\textbf`, should it?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You made me realize the problem seems to lie in the custom document class we have to use for the thesis, so I guess I'm on my own on this one for now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JimmyC Unless you can give a link to the source of the class, then it would be quite difficult for us to help you, yes.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - After expanding the code snippet into a full MWE, the bolding didn't show up until after the second compilation run.

Comment: @Mico I got boldface immediately.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added a download link to the package, if you feel up to the task!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the class `stpthesis` loads package `uufonts`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{uufonts}[2007/02/08 v1.2 UU fonts]
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{pbr}
\renewcommand*{\sfdefault}{mgs}
% No official recommendation from UU, but this seems to suit rather well.
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
% No official recommendation, but eulervm is cool since it uses one's
% standard font for digits etc.
\usepackage[small]{eulervm}
\endinput
```

`exempel.log` contains the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/pbr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11143.
```

Therefore I conclude that you have not installed the fonts of families `pbr` and `mgs`, needed for package `uuthesis`.

The fonts are not in TeX Live, thus you have asked, where you have got the class.

As workaround you can try class options `cm` or `times`, because they are using different fonts that are probably installed (guessing from the names).